# a tag without content become &nbsp; in page builder magento 2

Tags: magento2, page-builder

I wonder why `<a>` tag without content become `&nbsp;` in page builder.

Here i have this html code:

```
<ul class="links social">
   <li>
       <a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>
   </li>
</ul>
```

I paste this html code to "text" builder of page builder, and result i get is:

```
<ul class="links social">
    <li>&nbsp;</li>
</ul>
```

It remove the `<a>` tag and add `&nbsp;` instead.

Here's "text" builder of page builder:
[image]
[image]

Can some one help me on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh well, i've found a way to pass through this.

We use "HTML code" builder of page builder instead of "text" buider.

Worked perfectly for me.

[image]